# Where do I place the interface to change default form values, where such interface is restricted to certain users?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns, design

I'm designing an interface that will be used to update the `default` values for Cost/Day for a Quote. That interface to update costs will be used by admins/managers and is secured - aka visible to those with permissions to modify it.

Example below:

[image]

Question: Where to place such interface?

My two placement thoughts are:

- right there, next to the Quote itself.  I am party in favor of this as you don't have to remember or know where to change the defaults, you just go to the Quote, and it's all right there in one place
- move it another separate area, such as under the `Configure` menu item.  This is good too, since it "separates concerns" of "creating the quote" from "updating default pricing for the Quote form".  But separating concerns is more of a programming concept than an UX concept.  I wanted to see what UX says. Is there a school of thought for that or it depends?

Comment: Consider asking the admins, since they are the ones who will use the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Are admins familiar with the front-end? (What users see).

If they are, you could keep the "Cost per day" like you have it since it visually maps directly to the front-end. There is no doubt that they are editing the "200" value seen by users in that very same screen location.

[image]

If you move it to under "Configure", Admins might second guess exactly which piece of information they are editing in the front-end.

On a sidenote, I would add some space between those 2 rows to avoid association by proximity. Humans tend to read items close together as related.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go with the separate section as it is only restricted to few users and it will be accessible to only those users who have the rights. and invisible for those who can't edit and this approach doesn't create any confusion.